# Как разбить переменную на части в Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

На сайте используется шаблонизатор Smarty. Имеется такой код:

```
        <div class="coll f-address">
           {if $theme_settings.footer_address}
             {$theme_settings.footer_address}
           {/if} 
        </div>
```

в этой переменной `{$theme_settings.footer_address}` данные берутся из xml

```
...
<setting var="footer_address" control_type="text">
  <value>ООО "Дизайн.Решения";city, alabama ;mailz@mail.ru</value>
  <name locale="en_US">Footer addres</name>
  <name locale="ru_RU">Адрес в подвале</name>
</setting>
...
```

эти данные `<value>ООО "Дизайн.Решения";Москва, ;mailz@mail.ru</value>` выводятся в одну строку.
Подскажите, как можно разбить эту строку допустим по символу `;` и закинуть в тег `span` ?
С данным шаблонизатором ещё не работал 
Пытался сделать как-то так:

```
<?php $address = {$theme_settings.footer_address}; echo $address; ?>
```

но ничего не дало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{assign var=footerParts value=";"|explode:$theme_settings.footer_address}

{foreach $footerParts as $footerPart}
    {$footerPart}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: супер, благодарю

Comment: подготавливать надо данные только не на уровне шаблона, а на уровне логики